# A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute

Tags: wcf

I have created a simple WCF application to host in sharepoint server.

When deployed i got this error

```
A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.http://<MySharepointserver>:28000/_vti_bin/WCF/service.svc
```

Here is my service **Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="AssignmentCreatorMK1.ISAPI.ServiceBehaviour" name="AssignmentCreatorMK1.ISAPI.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" contract="AssignmentCreatorMK1.ISAPI.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AssignmentCreatorMK1.ISAPI.ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>     
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/> 
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

can somebdy please help me out here ?